# Twilio is undefined in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, twilio

I was trying to use twilio in my ionic 3 application. Twilio is working when I'm running it on a browser but when I tried to run it in an actual device it suddenly returns a `TypeError: undefined is not a function {stack: (...), message: "undefined is not a function"}`

In my index.html I import the twilio using cdn

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/releases/1.6.5/twilio.js"></script>`

then in my component:

`declare var Twilio: any;`

and use it like this:

`const device = Twilio.Device(token);`

Comment: try to provide a local copy of the twilio.js file, I'm guessing the device is not letting the app to download it. Depending on the type of device you might have to give permission, I'm not sure.

Comment: Yeah, I did try to have a local copy of it. but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you want to bundle the Twilio Client JS along with your app, you can actually [install it from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio-client) now.

```
npm install twilio-client
```

You can then use it with:

```
const Device = require('twilio-client').Device;
const device = Device(token);
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: yeah I think the undefine problem is fixed, but another error popped out.

`TypeError: Cannot set property 'audio' of undefined {stack: (...), message: "Cannot set property 'audio' of undefined"}`

Comment: Yup, definitely looks like an error. If you can’t figure out what’s going on your best bet is to ask a new question and share the relevant code.

Comment: okay, thank you very much philnash. I hope you help me again when I posted another question regardign with this. :P

Comment: I’ll see what I can do! 